# Editing rich text document (.rtf)

Tags: external-command, file-formats

In college sometimes we are not allowed to use MS Word (because we cant use autocorrect or the red underline) and I also want to use VIM so I can type quicker.

Is there a way how I can make and edit rich text documents while having access to things such as centurial text, bold, underline and colour etc.?

I have looked at [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1432) plugin but I am not sure if it does what I want and if so how to.

Thanks

Comment: But in Vim you can have red underline too.

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker. I did look at it but I thought it was for VIM only and it wouldn't show on other text editors such as `TextEdit`. I also wasn't sure if it would display the formatting in VIM. Thanks for confirming it.